# Shopify pageload progress bar never completing

Tags: shopify

I've built an app for Shopify which displays in a page in a store's admin section. The way that works is that an html page from my server is displayed inside an iframe on the Shopify admin.

When any page is loaded in the Shopify admin, a blue progress bar displays at the top; usually it progresses across the page pretty quickly and is gone. On my page, however, the bar progresses across the page very slowly and never finishes. My page is very small, and it displays almost instantaneously.

It seems like Shopify is looking for something in the background, but I don't know what it is. Do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the blue loading bar by calling [`ShopifyApp.Bar.loadingOff()`](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/embedded-app-sdk/methods#shopifyapp-bar-loadingoff). It would also be stopped if your app uses [`ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize(config)`](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/embedded-app-sdk/methods#shopifyapp-bar-initialize-config).